# dlopen fails in chroot

Tags: c, linux, dlopen, chroot

I'm attempting this: I have an environment defined in `/chroot/debian6.0/`
where I have bound some directories and created other ones. One is `libs/` which contains the library `libOne.so` and its dependencies
So:

```
/chroot/debian6.0/
               \--- libs/
                       \--- libOne.so
                       \--- other dependencies (*.so)
```

This library has been compiled in the chroot environment, and I want to open it with a process run from the containing environment.

This is the code:

#### remote.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res = 0;
    void* handle;

    /*chdir to first argument(path1)*/
    res = chdir(argv[1]);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("\nchdir: %s", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("\nError chdir %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /*chroot to path in first argument*/
    res = chroot(argv[1]);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("\nchroot: %s", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("\nError chroot %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /*Define path for dependencies*/
    putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/libs/");

    /*Opens library*/
    handle = dlopen(argv[2], RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening %s\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("\ndlopen: library %s opened\n", argv[2]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And I execute with the following command:

> ./remote "/chroot/debian6.0/Debian-6.0-chroot/" "/libs/libOne.so"

The result is an error when trying to dlopen the library.
Last lines of strace:

```
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0P#\0\000"..., 1024) = 1024
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=116600, ...}) = 0
old_mmap(NULL, 119656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7644000
mprotect(0xb7661000, 872, PROT_NONE)    = 0
old_mmap(0xb7661000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x1c000) = 0xb7661000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7f01000, 6291)                = 0
munmap(0xb7770000, 6496996)             = 0
munmap(0xb7757000, 98784)               = 0
munmap(0xb7662000, 1000332)             = 0
munmap(0xb7644000, 119656)              = 0
write(1, "chroot: /chroot/debian6.0/Deb"..., 48chroot: /chroot/debian6.0/Debian-6.0-chroot/
) = 48
write(1, "Error opening /libs/libD"..., 50Error opening /libs/libOne.so
) = 50
munmap(0xb7f03000, 4096)                = 0
_exit(1)                                = ?
```

The library appears to have all its dependencies - inside the chroot I can `ldd libOne.so` and I get

> > linux-gate.so.1 => (0xb7f16000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb78c6000)    libstdc++.so.6 =>
> >     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb77d1000)    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6
> >     (0xb77aa000)    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7665000)
> >     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7647000) /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> >     (0xb7f17000)

Any idea why the `dlopen` fails?  Or how to make it work?

---

Added perror and dlerror and I get:

```
Error opening library /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /libs/libOne.so)) = 117
```

---

UPDATE:

Although I have copied the libc version which I use to compile the program, to my containing environment and chroot' environment (both in /lib), i still get the same message on execution:

> Error opening library /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found
>   (required by /libs/libOne.so)) = 117

So i went to each lib folder and that's what i see:

**Containing Env:**

```
ll /lib
libc-2.2.4.so
libc.so.6 -> libc-2.2.4.so

ldd libc.so.6
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7dcc000)
```

**Chroot's env:**

```
ll /lib
libc.so.6 -> libc-2.11.3.so
libc-2.11.3.so

ldd libc.so.6
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7fb4000)
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7fb3000)
```

**In my Compiling Environment:**

```
ll /lib
libc.so.6 -> libc-2.11.3.so
libc-2.11.3.so

ldd libc.so.6
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf770f000)
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf770c000)
```

So it seems that my compiling and execution versions of libc.so.6 are the same, and linked to a second one which is the same, that is libc-2.11.3.so

So, I don't get why I'm getting *GLIBC_2.4 message*

**Last update:**
right now, after Petesh's guidance and using `dlmopen`, my strace throws next messages (at the end):

```
writev(2, [{"./remote", 5}, {": ", 2}, {"/lib/libdl.so.2", 15}, {": ", 2}, {"version \`GLIBC_2.3.4\' not found "..., 51}, {"\n", 1}], 6./remote: /lib/libdl.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.3.4' not found (required by ./remote) ) = 76
```

Comment: Do you have `ld.so` in your chroot?  Does `ldd <your library path>` (from a shell in the chroot) show that all the dependencies can be resolved?

Comment: Also, a minor style point - prefer `perror()` where appropriate for error messages, or `fprintf(stderr, ...)` (and using `strerror(errno)` - or `%m` on Glibc).

Comment: @Toby Speight Yes. 
From inside the jail:
    root@caja_1:/libs# ldd libOne.so
     linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f16000)
     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb78c6000)
     libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb77d1000)
     libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb77aa000)
     libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7665000)
     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7647000)
     /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f17000)

Comment: What's in `errno` after the failure?  See my hint of `perror()` in comment above.  I suggest you change the error message to include that information, then [edit] your question with the new code and the error message.

Comment: Note [Does `dlopen()` set `errno`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158005/does-dlopen-set-errno) to which the answer is 'No; use `dlerror()` to get the error information'.  What does `dlerror()` tell you?

Comment: I'mk having hard problems trying to edit my own question... added perror and dlerror and i get: Error opening library /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /libs/libOne.so)) = 117

Comment: That suggests that when you built `libOne.so`, you linked against a newer libc than the one available in the chroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in relation to `GLIBC_2.4` not being found is most likely caused because the invocation of `dlopen` occurs in a process that has already mapped in a copy of libc that doesn't expose that version.

So, we need to be a little bit creative, and use the secondary routine `dlmopen` rather than simple old `dlopen`.

dlmopen takes a parameter `lm_id` which is a namespace where it loads all the relevant libraries - if you use the default (`LM_ID_BASE`), it starts with the namespace that the program runs in; which for example would contain the `libc` that was loaded already when the application was launched.

So, rather than just calling `handle = dlopen(argv[2], RTLD_NOW);` we replace it with a call to:

```
handle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, argv[2], RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);
```

This will load fresh copies of all the libraries that `argv[2]` needs into the link address space used by that handle.

You can then reference symbols in the library using:

```
symbol = dlsym(handle, "symname");
```

and it should work.

I've changed your example slightly to make use of this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res = 0;
    void* handle;

    /*chdir to first argument(path1)*/
    res = chdir(argv[1]);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("\nchdir: %s", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("\nError chdir %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /*chroot to path in first argument*/
    res = chroot(argv[1]);
    if (res == 0) {
        printf("\nchroot: %s", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("\nError chroot %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /*Define path for dependencies*/
    putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/libs/");

    /*Opens library*/
    handle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, argv[2], RTLD_NOW); // needs _GNU_SOURCE
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening %s: %s\n", argv[2], dlerror());
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("\ndlopen: library %s opened\n", argv[2]);
    }

    int (*foo)(void);
    foo = (int (*)(void))dlsym(handle, argv[3]);
    if (foo == NULL) {
        printf("\nError referencing %s: %s\n", argv[3], dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", foo());

    return 0;

}
```

Now secondsly, the `putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/libs/");` doesn't do the needful - you cannot alter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the run-time of a program; the change will simply not be detected. Because your program is so simple we could do something at the start of the main like:

```
if (0 == getenv("RE_EXEC")) {
    putenv("RE_EXEC=1");
    putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/libs/");
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

which re-executes with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to `/libs` so it will search there.

There are a few other potential solutions - if the path setting is not suitable with the re-exec

You could make sure that `libOne.so` has `$ORIGIN` in the rpath for the binary. You can do this at compile/link time with:

```
-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
```

The quoting is to prevent the `$ORIGIN` from getting escaped by the shell. If this is in a `makefile` then you need to use the `$$` syntax for the target actions.

You can post-hoc patch the library with a tool like `patchelf` (on my system I did a simple `sudo apt-get install patchelf`):

```
patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN' libOne.so
```

This, of course relies on support for `$ORIGIN` in your `ld.so` (I cannot remember when it was added to `ld.so`; but it's been a few years); if your `ld.so` does not support `$ORIGIN` then you can always replace it with `/libs/`, and if you can't find `patchelf` for your distro, then you can always [build it yourself](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html)

Comment: thanks, maybe my putenv line is wrong or does nothing, but i'm afraid it's not a problem of defining the path for dependencies afterall.

Comment: This seems to be the solution as it prompts now that GLIBC_2.3.4 was not found. So on, i've found that the chroot's version is 2.2.4, and my compiling env's 2.11.3... there's a mess with the versions that i don't know how to resolve

Comment: I'm sorry i was wrong: both chroot's and compiling's environmet are GLIBC 2.11.3. Is my containing's environment which is version 2.2.4