# Does dlopen() set errno?

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

Everything is in the title really. The man page does not say anything. Some google reports some people checking errno after dlopen, but just few and with various results. The function does return a success/non-success value, but how should one figure out the cause of the failure.

So does `dlopen()` set errno? where are the different errno values defined, then? 
If not, what should be used to check what caused the failure?

Comment: `man dlopen` is clearly telling us about `dlerror`...

Comment: *Setting* `errno` is different from *effecting* `errno`.  It's quite possible for a call to `dlopen()` to *change* the value of `errno`.  For example, an `open()` call can fail as `dlopen()` tries to locate a library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP couldn't be bothered to read the man page for `dlopen`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[No](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) (emphasis added).

> Upon successful completion, *dlopen()* shall return a symbol table handle. If *file* cannot be found, cannot be opened for reading, is not of an appropriate executable object file format for processing by *dlopen()*, or if an error occurs during the process of loading file or relocating its symbolic references, *dlopen()* shall return a null pointer. **More detailed diagnostic information shall be available through [*dlerror()*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlerror.html)**.

---

As noted by others, nothing prohibits `dlopen()` (or, more likely, functions that `dlopen()` calls) from modifying `errno`.  But a standard-conforming `dlopen()` will not report its own errors through `errno`.  You need to call `dlerror()`.

Comment: OK, missed the man part about dlerror which I did not know about. And thanks Andrew for your comment, which surely explains why I felt I was on the track when errno changed...

Comment: Personally, I like to follow POSIX, which for me means checking Open Group's website instead of simply using the local manpages.  It is true that while most manpages follow a pattern, they aren't standardized, so error information may be in its own section, or may be in the "return value" section.

Comment: This answer is missing the fact that, while `dlopen` does not *set* (assign a meaningful value) to `errno`, it's permitted to *clobber* `errno` with any value other than zero (like all other functions not explicitly forbidden from doing so are permitted to do).